# Sharing a Document - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am sharing a Document from one of the folder in a Site, What i am looking forward for is to be able to only view the particular Document, But if i share that i end up with Visitor permissions to the site which i dont want to do.

is there a way i can only share the required document to the specific use and the user should not be able to see other stuff in the site?

any help will be appreciated! Thank you

Comment: are you sharing this with authenticated users or anonymous users

Comment: With Authenticated Users i guess, for the People in Company, But it could be as well that i might share that externally at some point

Answer (score 1):

You could share a file with people you specify can view.

[image]

Reference:

[Share SharePoint files or folders](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/share-sharepoint-files-or-folders-1fe37332-0f9a-4719-970e-d2578da4941c)